# Question about presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a project using the **View-Based Application** template.

In my `mainViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    UIImagePickerController *pickerController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    pickerController.delegate=self;

    [self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];
    [pickerController release];
}
```

I implemented the delegate already.

But when I was running this project, I didn't get the `imagePicker` View. Instead of the `imagePicker` View, the view of `mainViewController` was shown on screen.

Did I make some mistakes?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have put code in a wrong place `viewDidUnload` is called when a view unloads from memory. put your code into `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.